# Is it possible to force Windows 10 to display reminders about Daylight Savings?

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui, date-time

One of my favorite features about previous versions of Windows as opposed to Windows 10 is how it reminds users at least a week in advance about Daylight Savings, which is always nice since it gives me time to change my clocks and such. Since the clock is a frequently clicked on item, it provides a nice reminder without being intrusive.

However, I noticed in Windows 10, with the new "metro" clock, there are no longer any reminders about Daylight Savings in advance. Going forward, I find it likely that I, as well as others, are likely to forget about it altogether and that would cause problems since the newspaper may not provide a warning (and not everyone gets the paper either)

I heard recently that it is no longer possible to change a REG key to use the old Windows clock - that option is now gone. Is there any other way to show reminders? I also sort of miss the analog clock.

I was hoping to be able to get something like this in Windows 10 - if possible, I would like to accomplish this without third party software so it is easier to put in a Windows image and deploy:

[image]

Comment: Third-party software should exists that does this.

Comment: @Ramhound Any third party software in particular?

Comment: [Penteract Taskbar Analog Clock](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NT1D0W1JPCS) is supposed to inform you the day before. You can get the trial and change your system date to a day before the clock is supposed to change and see if it works.

Comment: @User42 Thanks, but it's ridiculous to need to use 3rd party software to get this basic functionality back. Windows 10 is broken in so many ways. I have no plans to downgrade from Windows 7 at this time.

Comment: @InterLinked :) . I just mentioned it because of the previous comments here.

Answer (score -2):

I hope this will help you: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/daylight-saving-time-windows

Just edit registry but I think you should have administrator privileges.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Daylight Savings reminders OR Windows 10. Did you even read my question? Remember that link-only answers are discouraged